# How to use Robocopy to copy a template folder structure to other folders?

Tags: robocopy

I need to copy all the folders within one folder, to multiple other folders. The folder structure I want to copy from is here:

```
x:\Customer1\Site1\
```

I want to copy all the folders within Site1, to all the folders within the following directory:

```
X:\Customer1\
```

Obviously I don't want to copy the folders back into Site1 again, only every folder within Customer1, excluding Site1.

Site1 contains 19 folders. I would like to end up having those 19 folders within every folder in the Customer1 folder. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

I have been looking at the Robocopy MS page to learn about all the switches and options, but there doesn't seem to be anything to help me with this 'copying folder tree from one folder to multiple folders' that I need. Please give me any reference

Many thanks
Naz

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is only possible with xcopy's `/t`-switch which copies only the folder structure (note that if you also want empty folders to get copied you have to put the '/e' -switch as well)

To copy the structure in every subfolder a for-loop is the way to go:

```
set customer1="X:\Customer1"
set site1="Site1"

for /f %%d in ('dir %customer1% /b /ad') do (
   if %%d NEQ %site1% xcopy %customer1%\%site1%\*.* %customer1%\%%d\*.* /t /e   
)
```